# TCPDF custom footer (HTML!)

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I found how to create custom footers with TCPDF, but this is only applying with text. Is there any possibility to use html? There is a function called "writeHTMLCell" but it needs x and -coordinates which I think is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get X and Y coordinates using the getX() and getY() functions of TCPDF Class.

Comment: of course i can, BUT i dont know the height and width of my custom footer. So, i.e. if i start at getY()-50 and my footer is higher than 50, what will then happen? Similar problem: I wanna center my footer, how can i set the x coordinate if i dont know how wide my footer is.

Comment: It's simple. Create another TCPDF document with 0 margin, write the text that you want to write in footer in this document and get the value of X and Y coordinates using above functions and discard the document....This is not the best practice though but there is no way of knowing the accurate height of a cell without writing.